# CSS button styling and alignment

Tags: css, html, button, divide

I'm a newbie to CSS styling and so far I'm able to get my text aligned.

However, I'm unable to apply styles to my buttons and align them side by side underneath the text. I would like to give each button a different colour.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#weather{
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="weather">
  <p>Temperature:  &deg;</p>
  <p>Humidity:  %</p>
  <p>LED:</p>
</div>
<div id="ON" class="button">
  <input type="submit" value="LED ON" onclick="ledOn()">
  <input type="submit" value="LED OFF" onclick="ledOff()">
  <form action="index.html" target="_newtab">
    <input type="submit" value="Data History" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: try to change styles for `.button`: add `margin: 0 auto;  width: 300px;` and replace `display: inline-block;` with `display: block;`

Comment: @Banzay your suggestion aligns the text underneath the text in blocks. I want to align each button side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to display the form as an inline element (like `<span>`). Use `display: inline` for this.
2. You can give each button an ID and then change their individual CSS, as well as set common properties for the group of buttons.

See the code snippet for the full example.

```css
#weather{
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
  /*background: #ecf0f1;*/
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline;
}
#led-on,
#led-off,
#data-history {
  border-color: #333;
  color: white;
}
#led-on {
  background: #1abc9c;
}
#led-off {
  background: #e74c3c;
}
#data-history {
  background: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<div id="weather">
  <p>Temperature:  &deg;</p>
  <p>Humidity:  %</p>
  <p>LED:</p>
</div>
<div id="ON" class="button">
  <input id="led-on" type="submit" value="LED ON" onclick="ledOn()">
  <input id="led-off" type="submit" value="LED OFF" onclick="ledOff()">
  <form action="index.html" target="_newtab">
     <input id="data-history" type="submit" value="Data History" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you get rid of the background colour?

Comment: In the .button CSS selector remove the "background: #ecf0f1" line or change it to background: #none (which is what removing it does anyway).

I can edited my code snippet so try it again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution.

To align all buttons you need set `display: inline-block` to form.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#weather{
  font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.button {
 /* background-color: #4CAF50;  Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
form {
display: inline-block;
}
div > input:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
div > input:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
form > input {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="weather">
  <p>Temperature:  &deg;</p>
  <p>Humidity:  %</p>
  <p>LED:</p>
</div>
<div id="ON" class="button">
  <input type="submit" value="LED ON" onclick="ledOn()">
  <input type="submit" value="LED OFF" onclick="ledOff()">
  <form action="index.html" target="_newtab">
    <input type="submit" value="Data History" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get rid of the green banner behind the button?

Comment: remove `background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */` from `.button` rules

Answer (score 1):

1. Link your CSS to your HTML
2. Put an ID to each of your buttons (this is to style them differently)
3. In your CSS, style the buttons with this code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#led-on {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
#led-off {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="weather">
    <p>Temperature: &deg;</p>
    <p>Humidity: %</p>
    <p>LED:</p>
  </div>

  <div id="ON" class="button">
    <input id="led-on" type="button" value="LED ON">
    <input id="led-off" type="button" value="LED OFF">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok for one you are using type="submit" instead of type="button". Secondly you should be adding the class to your actual buttons like so

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="LED ON" onclick="ledOn()">
```

Just to go a little more in depth,
You can also style with this css

```
input[style=button]{
background-color: green;
}
```

that will style all buttons green, you can then narrow that down even more by adding classes or id selectors like

```
#ON input[style=button]{
background-color: green;
}
```

To color each individual button you need to either assign an inline style so

```
<input type="button" style="background-color: green">
```

for each one or give each one a different class or id the example below adds a new class as well as keeping the style of your button uniform.

```
  body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
     #weather{

        font-family: 'Helvetica', Helvetica monospace;
        font-size: 2em;
        line-height: 0.5em;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
         text-align: center;
    }
    .button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
    .green{
          background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
          }
    .red{
      background-color: red;
    }
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="weather">
 <p>Temperature:  &deg;</p>
 <p>Humidity:  %</p>
 <p>LED:</p>
</div>
<div id="ON">
 <input type="button" class="button green" value="LED ON" onclick="ledOn()">
 <input type="button" class="button red" value="LED OFF" onclick="ledOff()">
 <form action="index.html" target="_newtab">
  <input type="submit" value="Data History" />
 </form>
</div>
```

As you can see here the main difference is that each button now has two classes. One defines the button style and the other defines the color. This is only one way of doing it, you could use the input[style=button] to define the look of all your buttons and only use the one class or you could create individual classes for each different button, you could also add ID's to the buttons and use the #id selector to add your style but I personally have found this to be an easier way to manage your coding.

Comment: Thanks! How can i add different colours to the different buttons

Comment: Please try to provide a answer here to the question, you can comment on the question for suggestions.

Comment: Would love to add a comment but I currently am not allowed to, I am editing my answer to include a better more thorough answer

Comment: @PeterWaters Thanks for the solution. How can I add spaces to the buttons and shrink them to 3/4 the current size. Please see [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekom89/Ltfak2vw/)

Comment: Add height and width to your button code, this will let you adjust the size of the buttons to get your perfect size. As for spaces if you mean spaces between the buttons then you can use Margin to do so.

Comment: @PeterWaters the buttons are aligned to the left not the centre how can i change this?

Comment: I've added a little extra to this fiddle for you [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c13cm3a8/)